# how do you do sql count in pig , count(var2 ) group by var1 ?

Tags: apache-pig, hue

so I have pig script below .. here I am able to group by var1 , then concatenate var2 values into one line by var1 , how can I do something similar to 
**var1,  count(var2 ) group by var1**

```
data = load 'inputP2' using textloader as (var1:int, var2:int);
result = group data by var1;
store result into 'outputP2';
```

Comment: Instead of textloader use PigStorage() . Ex: data = load 'inputP2' using PigStorage('<your delimiter'>) as (var1:int, var2:int);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `COUNT` function to get the result. Can you try this?

```
cnt = FOREACH result GENERATE group,COUNT(data.var2);
store cnt into 'outputP3';
```

Reference:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#count